# How to start Java application with console suppressed on Mac

Tags: java, macos, console

I've written an application in JAVA and I've installed it to run via launchctl (basically cron).

The problem I'm having is every time the job fires, I briefly see "Java" in the Menu Bar and keyboard control is taken away from me (again briefly but enough to annoy).

How can I stop the application from doing this?  Is there anything in launchctl that I can do?  I know there are other applications launchctl is firing off that don't exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Do I get this right: The problem is not the JAVA Part but the launchctl program that displays a console to you instead of silently starting the java program? If so, you might want to rephrase your question to: "How to start Java Program on Mac without displaying console?" Keep in mind that here on SO we try to focus on the actual problem. Its good that you posted your current solution and why its not as good as you want it. But please also state the intended goal as clear as possible.

Comment: Also, Welcome to Stack Overflow! You question currently has 4 "on hold" votes. At 5 it will get an "on hold" notice. As soon as you have [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27211444/edit) the question to contain the intended goal it will go into a "continue review" process.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't the Mac or LaunchCtl.  The problem had to do with some JavaFX that I was installing into the application.  The class that contained "main" was extended by javafx.application.Application.  In situations where I wasn't starting the UI (it can run headless as well) because of JavaFX "Application" was taking over anyway.

The resolution was to create another class that extends "Application".  I only instantiate and run that class when I'm needing the UI to start up.

Here's the application's main

BEFORE
public class MyApp 
       extends Application {

```
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage)
          throws IOException {
  ...
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
          throws Exception {
    UIMain uiMain;
    uiMain = new UIMain();

    if (args.length == 0) {
      uiMain.run(args);
    } else {
    // Even though there is no UI being launched it still popped "Java" in the toolbar here
...
    }
  }
}
```

AFTER (there may be a better way to do this)

```
public class MyApp {

  public static void main(String[] args)
          throws Exception {
    UIMain uiMain;
    uiMain = new UIMain();

    if (args.length == 0) {
      uiMain.run(args);
    } else {
    // When this section runs I don't get the annoying Java pop in the Toolbar
... 
    }
}
```

```java
public class UIMain
        extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage)
          throws IOException {
...
  }

  public void run(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

}
```